# How reload Object property changes in DOM element in vue?

Tags: vue.js

I need to show the status of an object if it has a property or not. I add a property `id` to object and `console.log` shows it is true, But it is  not updated in DOM element.
How can I see the status in DOM element?

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      children: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fillChildren() {
      this.children['id'] = 'child1Id'
      console.log(this.children.hasOwnProperty('id')) // This is true
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <div @click="fillChildren">Fill children</div>
  {{children.hasOwnProperty('id')}} <!-- I want to see true after click -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Reactivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects):

> Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion.

You can circumvent this limitation by using the `vm.$set` instance method:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      children: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fillChildren() {
      this.$set(this.children, 'id', 'child1Id')
      console.log(this.children.hasOwnProperty('id')) // This is true
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <div @click="fillChildren">Fill children</div>
  {{children.hasOwnProperty('id')}} <!-- I want to see true after click -->
</div>
```